# Can you be offside from a goal kick?

Tags: rules, football

Can you be offside from a goal kick? Looking for official FIFA laws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Law 11 *Offside*, part 3 *No offence* makes explicit exception:

> There is no offside offence if a player receives the ball directly from:
>
> - **a goal kick**
> - a throw-in
> - a corner kick

even if the player is otherwise in an offside position.

Once ball is touched by another player, Law 11 applies as normal.